# How to fix 'list' object has no attribute 'render' error when using YOLO object detection

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch

I'm following an object detection tutorial using yolo and this piece of code always throws the same error however is copied correctly. anyone know why? Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFNJGim3FXw time stamp is about 17 minutes.

Code:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def main():

    model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

    results = model('E:/03_files/programing/Neural_Networks/APEX_Aimbot/test.jpg')

    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(results.render()))
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:
image 1/1

```
E:\03_files\programing\Neural_Networks\APEX_Aimbot\test.jpg: 384x640 1 horse, 119.0ms
Speed: 6.0ms preprocess, 119.0ms inference, 5.0ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\03_files\programing\Neural_Networks\APEX_Aimbot\test.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "e:\03_files\programing\Neural_Networks\APEX_Aimbot\test.py", line 17, in main
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(results.render()))
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'render'
```

I have looked all over the internet but cannot find anyone with a similar problem. I have even tried chat gpt but that also has not clue how to fix it and just leads me in circles.

I expect the code to simple output the image with boundary boxes.

Comment: That means `model` returns a list, not an object that has a `render` method. Have you checked the docs for `YOLO`?

Comment: The `model()` function is returning a list, which doesn't have a `render()` function. I'm guessing you need to convert it to something which does.

Comment: The video doesn't show `model` being assigned the returned value of calling `YOLO`.

Comment: The question must contain a complete [mre] with the file and sufficient code to reproduce the error. No one is likely to go watch that 1h15min video to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
def main():

    model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

    results = model('E:/03_files/programing/Neural_Networks/APEX_Aimbot/test.jpg')
 
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(results.render()[0]))
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```